# Delete OLE Object Data from Access Database using SQL VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

So I've created a database Access 2012 and an application written in VB.net. I can successfully save and retrieve an image to and from the database when I use OLE Object as the data type for that field. The problem however is I want to create the ability to remove that data from the record and still save the record.  I can't figure out how to either clear simply that field from the current row or how to save a blank byte over top of the existing data?

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Have you tried setting the value of the field to `DBNull.Value`?

Answer (score 0):

You can either update the existing records field with:

- SQL: NULL
- VB: DBNull.Value
- EF: Nothing

Or, what most people do is delete the record if it is no longer needed.

```
DELETE FROM [Table Name] WHERE [PK Field Name] = @PK
```